# how to restore all windows when open JetBrains IDE again

Tags: windows-10, ide, intellij-idea, pycharm, webstorm

I usually use one JetBrains IDE window for one folder(project).

I need to shut down the computer every day.

Is there any way to restore all closed windows when I continue the work the next day?

I am using window10.

(ps: in mac, seems mac provide the function of restore **all** windows  when logged back in, but window sadly didnt have this)

Comment: Windows actually does support this.  However, if it's supported depend on the version of Windows 10 you are running and if the application supports it.

Comment: do you have **Reopen projects on startup** enabled in IDE preferences (**Settings | Appearance & Behavior | System Settings**)? When this option is ON, all IDE windows are normally restored on IDE restart

Comment: @lena seems that only one project (one window) could be restored for this setting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems one approach is

don't manually close all windows before you shut down the computer.

Directly press shutdown in window10.